# CSS Flexbox align-items and justify-content

Tags: css, flexbox

For CSS Flexbox layouts, I have been given to understand that we have align-items property to align our item on the cross axis, while we use justify-content to align the item on the main axis.

Now does the above statement applicable only with the default flex-direction i.e. row

Does it change when we use flex-direction as column.

So essentially, I am confused with how the behavior of align-items and justify-content when we have flex-direction as column ?

**Example**

On following link
https://jsbin.com/wakagup/edit?html,output

```
.box {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-start;
    justify-content: flex-start;
  }
```

If we change align-items from flex-start to flex-end, the divs seem to move horizontally rather than vertically which is what is confusing me.

Also, the divs move differently when we remove flex-direction: column; and try different values for the align-items/justify-content

Comment: Have you tried it out? Let the browser teach you.

Comment: Yes, let me add a very specific example

Comment: From my experience it applies to both directions.

Comment: Added link of what I am referring to

Comment: Some [ressources](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) that can help

Comment: Add that example to directly in your post, as a snippet. Don't force people to leave the site!

Comment: consider the duplicate question and also follow the different links provided there, you will understand everything about flexbox

Answer (score 0):

When the direction is inverted the axis inverts thus the opposite behavior.

> The flex-direction CSS property sets how flex items are placed in the
>   flex container defining the main axis and the direction (normal or
>   reversed). - [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-direction)